# Decrease in Intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, scattering, collision

A beam of particles pass through a target made of thin foil of a very
small thickness $\Delta x$ having $N$ particles per unit volume. Let the collision cross section be $\sigma$ . If the intensity of the beam ( number of particles per unit area per unit time) is I to start with what would be the decrease in the intensity in terms of $N$      ,  $\Delta x$ , and $\sigma$ ?

Comment: Specific, narrowly defined homework questions are not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider a very small sheet of thickness $dx \ll \Delta x$ within your foil, in which the intensity barely decreases : $I(x+dx)\simeq I(x)$.
2. Then, you can easily calculate the number of particles within that sheet (that's $N*dx$ per unit area)
3. Now you get the total cross section of those particles (per unit area). That gives you the decrease in beam intensity through that very small sheet $I(x+dx)-I(x)$.
4. Integrate over $x$ (so that you're adding the effect of your infinitesimal sheets) from $0$ to $\Delta x$.